# How can I unit test the view models of a WPF user control

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, mvvm, moq

How can I mock the creation of `ChildViewModel`s in `ChildrenViewModel`:

```
IChildViewModel c = new ChildViewModel(child);
children.Add(c);
```

I'm using `ChildViewModel` (**there is no `ChildView`!**) since a `Child` (model) class does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. **UPDATE:** One of the reasons why I introduced `ChildViewModel` that encapsulates a `Child` is a validation requirement. **Domain model** objects should **always** be **valid** (e.g. the child's name mustn't consist a digit). Nevertheless, the textbox should display invalid values. In this very simple example, `ChildrenView` consists of a DataGrid that lists the `ChildViewModels`. The user can see invalid names in the DataGrid "name" column but the child objects are always valid.

`ChildrenView` is a user control:

```
<views:ChildrenView ChildrenAware="{Binding SelectedItem.ChildrenAware, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

`ChildrenViewModel` is created in the resources of `ChildrenView`:

```
<viewModels:ChildrenViewModel x:Key="ViewModel"/>
```

**My aim**: I want to test that the ObservableCollection (with type argument `ChildViewModel`) is filled up with (mocked) `ChildViewModel` objects.

**The problem**: The parameterless constructor is executed why I can't use constructor injection (and inject a component that can create `ChildViewModel`s).

**The question**: I can see two solutions: Using property injection or a `StaticClass` that has a set/get property of type `IViewModelFactory` that I can mock:

```
var mockFactory = new Mock<IViewModelFactory>();
mockFactory.Setup(m => m.CreateChildViewModel(mockChild.Object))
           .Returns(mockChildViewModel);

StaticClass.ViewModelFactory = mockFactory.Object;
```

Are there any others? Which one should I choose?

Comment: Can you post your complete unit tests? It's hard to guess what you are trying to test

Comment: You don't, because you don't create ViewModels for your UserControls.  This is a code smell, and results in heartbreak and loss of sleep.  Think about this--does a TextBox have a TextBoxViewModel?  No.  You bind ***your VM*** to the public properties of the TextBox.  UserControls should be designed the same way.

Comment: @Will: add as answer, it deserves upvoting. Also, that way it'll be searchable, and more useful.

Comment: @lll: I want to test that the ObservableCollection (with type argument ChildViewModel) is filled up correctly (without executing ChildViewModel code).

Comment: @SunnyMilenov that's a side note, and not what this OP has an issue with.  I've got a number of answers on questions where the OP is at an impasse because they are using a UC VM.

Comment: Did answer help, no?

Answer (score 1):

> The problem: The parameterless constructor is executed why I can't use
>   constructor injection (and inject a component that can create
>   ChildViewModels).

Maybe I'm not understanding your question entirely. Why wouldn't you?

If your `ViewModel` is like

```
public class ChildrenViewModel
{
    public ChildrenViewModel()
    {}

    public ChildrenViewModel(IViewModelFactory<IChildViewModel> factory)
    {
        ChildViewModels = new ObservableCollection<IChildViewModel>(factory.Create());
    }

    public ObservableCollection<IChildViewModel> ChildViewModels { get; set; }
}
```

Then dummy test could be

```
[TestMethod]
public void ChildViewModelsCreatedTest()
{
    var factory = new Mock<IViewModelFactory<IChildViewModel>>();
    factory.Setup(f => f.Create())
        .Returns(new List<IChildViewModel>() { new ChildViewModel() });

    var vm = new ChildrenViewModel(factory.Object);
    Assert.IsNotNull(vm.ChildViewModels);
    Assert.IsTrue(vm.ChildViewModels.Count == 1);
}
```